# Mocking an object defined in a class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

With the following code:

```
class Client {
    private Service _service;

    public Client() {
        _service = new Service; // Connection is made to endpoint
    }

    public string GetData() {
        return _service.ReadData();
    }
}
```

How can Service be mocked using Moq without making modifications to the constructor or access-modifiers?

Comment: Service is an instance, so you can't mock it.  Service should implement a interface, then you can mock it,  You really should ctor inject it at that point

Comment: @BigDaddy I could create an interface that Service can implement, but with ctor injection, the job of creating the service is offloaded elsewhere. The intention of Client is to create the service.

Comment: Isn't it the Client's intention to 'use' the service.  You need to depend on the abstraction and not the concretion.  You don't need a DI container to do this either.   The instantiator of Client can inject the Service.  If you want to do unit testing, you'll need to inject your dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emphasize this again:

- If your `new Service()` constructor is connecting to the endpoint, you will not be able to mock this code. UnitTests should never depend on another endpoint being available, even if you replace the instance afterwards.
- If `Service` does not provide a mockable Interface `IService` and its methods are not virtual, you will not be able to mock it at all. You would need to create a wrapper interface and implementation

A common workaround would be to create a **second** constructor with restricted visibility (e.g. internal) and use that to inject a mock into your class. You can control visibility by using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. There are some discussions about creating constructors just for tests, but that is a possible first step in the right direction.

```
class Client {
    private Service _service;

    // Only for UnitTests
    internal Client(Service service) {
        _Service = service
    }

    public Client() {
        _service = new Service(); // Connection is made to endpoint
    }

    public string GetData() {
        return _service.ReadData();
    }
}
```

Just putting together the stuff from all the comments into a usable example:

```
class Client {
    private IService _service;

    Client(IService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    public string GetData() {
        return _service.ReadData();
    }
}

class ClientFactory {

    public Client CreateClient(){
        var service = new Service(); // Connection is made to endpoint
        return new Client(service);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well as it doesn't require a change in the architecture to begin mocking with.

Answer (score 3):

For that to be possible (or at least, cleanly done), you have to do **dependency injection**. Your class should not instantiate the Service. It should receive an already instantiated instance of the service.

```
class Client {
    private Service _service;

    public Client(Service service) {
        _service = service; // maybe you check for null or other checks here
    }

    public string GetData() {
        return _service.ReadData();
    }
}
```

Next step : you should set your class to **depend on an interface** IService instead of on the actual Service class. This way, you can easily create another ServiceMock that can be injected instead of the Service when you instantiate your class.

```
class Client {
    private IService _service;

    public Client(IService service) {
        _service = service; // maybe you check for null or other checks here
    }

    public string GetData() {
        return _service.ReadData();
    }
}
```

---

Related to your requirement :

> without making modifications to the constructor or access-modifiers?

That is not a good practice, and it can get really dirty. I don't have a solution like that, given that you use the direct type and not an interface.

I don't know if you are working on some legacy code or third party library, but anticipation on this kind of problems by programming to interfaces instead of classes is the key here.

Comment: Could you expand on the "class should not instantiate the Service"? The intent of Client is to work with Service privately so no other class needs to know about or be coupled with Service.

Comment: But then you can't mock it.

Comment: Maybe you can add some pattern on the top of that, some factory maybe. But if "no other class needs to know what happens", it looks like encapsulated, and so your tests shouldn't know about it either.

Comment: The problem is not that other classes *could* know about your service. The problem is that, as it is now, your class *cannot know anything else than the concrete Service* . So you cannot uncouple it and use another "fake service" instead.

Comment: Don't be afraid to "reverse the dependencies" . Just create another middle-class in your actual production code that take care of instantiating the Service (so the other classes still don't know about it). Your encapsulation logic is still like you had it, just the new middle-class knows about "Service", and now you removed the tight coupling between Client and Service, so you can mock another IService in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have thought about instantiating Service elsewhere but I've been conflicted about offloading the coupling especially since the constructor for Service connects to the endpoint and may throw errors handled in Client. As you guessed, Service is a third-party library.

Comment: If you feel the need to test the behavior of your client by mocking the Service, then it is the way to go. But, yes, as a trade off, you need some more engineering to handle the Service instantiation itself separately, with separate exception handling.